# Install SSDT for VS 2017 - Missing Integration Services

Tags: ssis, ssdt, visual-studio-2017

I have downloaded and installed SSDT from [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#ssdt-for-vs-2017-standalone-installer). The install was successful and I now have SSDT for VS 2017 installed - version 15.8.9 (as per screenshot)

However, I cannot create an SSIS project. There is no option in SSDT to do so.

When I try to open an old version of an SSIS package I get the below 'Unsupported'...

[image]

What else am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Which is the version of that 'old SSIS package'?

Comment: 2008R2. However, I cannot create a new SSIS package either. No business intelligence option in VS 2017 SSDT

Comment: According to docs, supported versions for SSIS are: `Integration Services packages SQL Server 2012 – SQL Server 2017`

Comment: Just to cover all the bases... when you ran the separate SSDT installer, did you tick the box for Integration Services?

Comment: Yes. I will try uninstall and reinstall SSDT

Comment: Just did a Repair of SSDT and it worked! Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repairing the installation of SSDT resolved the issue.